# How can I rewrite my controller URL?

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am developing my website using ASP.NET MVC 5 in Visual Studio 2013. Now, the project has several controllers that are related and are like this (* represents Details/Index/Edit/Delete):

```
Current URL                  Desired URL
/Billing/                    /Billing
/BillableItems/              /Billing/BillableItems
/Customers                   /Billing/Customers
/Bills                       /Billing/Bills
/BilledItems                 /Billing/BilledItems
```

It is like that because the simplistic project template only allows for that. HOWEVER, since these items are all relatedto billing I would like to group them as one such that the Billing Controller URLs would look as if there were sub-controllers for each of the entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use an Area. If you create an Area in your project called `Billing`, then you can put all of these related controllers under that area and all the URLs will be prefixed with the Area name, "Billing".
2. Use custom routes or attribute routing. Attribute routing is far easier and built-in since you're using MVC5. Just prefix your controllers with `[RoutePrefix("Billing/[ControllerName]"]`. For example, with your `CustomersController`:

   ```
   [RoutePrefix("Billing/Customers")]
   public class CustomersController : Controller
   ```

   You'll of course need to enable attribute routing for this to work and apply proper route attributes to the actions in your controller(s). See [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) for more information.

   With traditional routing you'll just need to set up a route for each of your controllers:

   ```
    routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Customers",
       url: "Billing/Customers/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Index", id = UrlParameters.Optional }
    );
   ```

   Remember to place those routes *before* your default route so they catch first.